# Laravel Issue while connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-connection, wampserver

I'm trying to connect to mysql database using laravel php framework.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
"Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"


Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php
48
```

Most replies on questions like this, was to increase the execution time, but in my case I'm just trying simple insert query. and I think the error is a failed connection, and the query is not reached...

Here is my database.php configuration file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'mysql',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '5000',
            'database' => 'valet',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '123456',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Note that I'm runing wamp server on port 5000.

Comment: "_wamp server on port 5000_" Does that include the MysqlServer? Have you tried the standard MysqlServerPort 3306 in your `database.php`? (I think only your Apache Server is running on port 5000)

Comment: Yes @kerbholz I tried both of them, an both not working..

Comment: by the way you are right, according to my.ini file mysql is using 3306 port, but the error still exists, there is something else...

Comment: I usually keep `database.php` untouched and adjust mysql settings in `.env`. Also, you might need to `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes to config files.

Comment: I changed database.php in a hope to get rid of this issue, and now I tried the config:cache but the error still exists.By the way, thanks for your hint it's the first time I know that I "need to php artisan config:cache after you make changes to config files"

Comment: So did u find solution?

Comment: _Note that I'm runing wamp server on port 5000._ Are you? Normally that means you are running Apache on port 5000, not MySQL. Unless you are sure you are running MYSQL on port 5000, try using setting port 3306, the default MySQL port, on your MySQL configuration

Comment: When I changed it back to 3306, it wasn't worked untill I ran the command:Php artisan config:cache, as it was mentioned by @kerbholz comment. Can you post it as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the changes (set your database port) in `.env` or `config/database.php`.

Make sure to run `php artisan config:cache` to clear and cache Laravel's config.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your script is executed for more then 60 seconds and that why it was terminated.
2. There is a value in `php.ini` defining maximum time PHP script can run.
3. Just update the value (it's called `max_execution_time`)

Comment: That's impossible! I'm just trying a simple insert query for a two columns table structure...

Comment: I just gave you response for your problem: "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded". Check it maybe it is set on 1 sec?

Comment: Although it's set to 120 in php.ini file, it gives the error at 60, even when I changed it to 1400 still giving the error at 60..

Comment: check also: max_input_time

Comment: I know and for sure I appreciate your help, your response is true for some cases, but not on my case.

Comment: also remember to restart server after changing php.ini